# Change kernel of bootable ISO File

Tags: boot, kernel, iso

I need a bootable ISO file with Linux Kernel 4.5+. However, I could not find how to change the kernel of an ISO file.

The [official site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Live_CD_Kernel) says to change the "vmlinuz" file.However, I don't have another vmlinuz file. I just have source code from ubuntu kernel site. (Available at the end of this post)

For example, I want to use [Linux Kernel 4.7.3](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.3/)

Can you tell me where to get/how to create vmlinuz file and as a result iso file?

Thank you so much,

Comment: What you mentioned in your solution definitely worked! Thanks for that! However, Pinguy didn't worked correctly with Kubuntu 16.04. But worked amazingly on Kubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at this wrong, first install ubuntu to a hdd or a `persistent` usb so you can make changes.

Now it is installed you can download and install the kernel you want

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.3/linux-headers-4.7.3-040703_4.7.3-040703.201609070334_all.deb]
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.3/linux-headers-4.7.3-040703-generic_4.7.3-040703.201609070334_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.3/linux-image-4.7.3-040703-generic_4.7.3-040703.201609070334_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i 'linux-headers-4.7*.deb' 'linux-image-4.7*.deb'
```

Now reboot

`sudo reboot`

Now you can use something like [Pinguy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/) (a remastersys fork)

```
wget downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pinguy-os/ISO_Builder/pinguybuilder_4.3-8_all-beta.deb?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fpinguy-os%2Ffiles%2FISO_Builder%2F&ts=1473803400&use_mirror=heanet
sudo dpkg -i pinguybuilder_4.3-8_all-beta.deb
```

To create an exact copy of the running system, including the kernel and any other changes you wish to make and it should give you a bootable ISO at the end.

Alternatively, you can now just pull the `vmlinuz` and `initrd.gz` from the working system's `/boot` folder and add it to your ISO.

Comment: How to copy initrd? System has `initrd.img` while live iso has `initrd.lz` file which contains initrd. So copying won't work. How to repack initrd.img to initrd.lz ?

Comment: Can you answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> The official site says to change the "vmlinuz" file.However, I don't have another vmlinuz file. I just have source code from ubuntu kernel site.

You can find this file in the linux-image-x.x.x-xxxxxx-generic package.

```
$ dpkg -c linux-image-4.7.3-040703-generic_4.7.3-040703.201609070334_amd64.deb | grep vmlinuz
-rw------- root/root   4134688 2016-09-07 09:45 ./boot/vmlinuz-4.7.3-040703-generic
```